# How would one calculate the percent error on a vote?

Tags: sampling, prediction

Maybe I'm not asking for the right measure.  Basically, there are 9million votes already in, and 4.8million no, and 4.2million yes.  There are a million votes left to count.  What are the chances that the true outcome of the vote was really a yes?  (800,000 would have to be yes votes of the remaining million).

Comment: The short answer--which is well understood by pollsters and even the news media--is that you cannot tell from this information alone, because the nine million votes already in are almost always *not* a random, or even representative, sample of all ten million votes. Without additional information about how the vote returns may be related to voting behavior, statistics has little or nothing to offer apart from this negative assessment.

Comment: A recent related question is found [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43017/really-a-knifes-edge).